# Give or gift? That is the question

Tags: word-usage

Used be, one gave a gift. It was called gifting, the gift was given.

When, why and how did "gift" replace "give" as in "I gifted her a bouquet"?

"Gifted" used mean talented eg "a gifted musician".

Comment: Consider this article by Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/gift-as-a-verb

Comment: Merriam-Webster says gift has been used as a verb for 400 years, but offers no citation. Bad scholarship.

Answer (score -1):

"to give" means to pass something from someone to someone else
"to gift" means to pass *ownership* to someone without any payment - to (make a) present.

The difference is: if you buy something from me, you will *give* me money and I will *give* you the goods. Would I *give* you the something as *gift* (would i *gift* you something, that is: as a *present*), I would still *give* you something but you wouldn't *give* me anything in return.

> I gifted her a bouquet?

You gave (your girlfriend?) a bouquet *as a present*. In the flower shop  the florist *gave* you the bouquet - in exchange for money, because you *bought* it. Would they have *gifted* you the bouquet instead of selling it to you they will most likely go out of business soon.

> gifted musician

It was a common belief that talent was bestowed upon you by some higher instance. Since there was no quid pro quo for that, the talent was considered a gift - a present. Someone "gifted" did not have his remarkable skills because he worked hard and practiced a lot, but because he got it - for free - from above.

Comment: Not true. Oxford Languages gives as its main definition for **give** "freely transfer the possession of (something) to (someone)." It _can_ also mean "pass something to someone" as in "Give me your coat" (to hang up).

Comment: @KateBunting: so, your problem is that my explanation lacks the word "freely"?

Comment: I'd answer: What *gives*?

Comment: No, my problem is that you imply that _give_ doesn't mean 'transfer ownership/possession' - which it does and always has done. We've always spoken of 'giving a present'.

Comment: ... ie "to give" means to physically pass something from someone to someone else **_OR_** to pass ownership to someone without any payment – to (make a) present. Amongst other things. 'Gift' is less polysemous as a verb (but also rarer; it is probably most often used in the 'present on a plate' sense: _Huggins gifted the Brazilians their opening goal_) and is otherwise very formal. Ignoring the common stative passive usage 'She is gifted with incredible artistic skills', where the adjective-or-verb? debate will be raised.

Comment: @KateBunting: as to my knowledge, I have not implied such a thing. But, of course, you are free to read whatever you want into what I write, I'll *give you that*. "To give" does indeed not mean "transfer of ownership", at maximum it means "transfer of possession". If I *give you the key to my apartment* you *possess* it, but you don't necessarily *own* it - neither the key nor the apartment.

Comment: The way you phrased your answer - italicising _ownership_ - appears to imply that you think _give_ can only mean 'hand something to somebody'. We've been 'giving' presents for centuries; the use of _gift_ as a verb is new, as the OP says.

Comment: @KateBunting: "ownership" is a legal term (like possession). A "gift" is something *given* but including the transfer of ownership. If I *give* something to you, it is a transfer of possession and it might (or not) include a transfer of ownership. If i *gift* you with something, not only is the possession transferred but *also is the ownership*! What I gifted you belongs no longer to me but to you. This - one *may* include transfer of ownership, the other *always includes ownership* - is the distinction between "to give" and "to gift" in this regard.